# Object value is undefined : MEAN Stack

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, mean-stack

This is my code

```
//to check whether email exist or not
router.post('/forgot', function(req,res) {
  User.find({email: req.body.email}, function(err,found) {
    console.log('finding email');
    if(found.length) {
      //console.log(found);
      resets(found);
       return res.json({success: true, msg: 'User found'});
      //return res.json(found);
    }
    else if(err) {
      return res.json({success: false, msg: 'User not found'});
    }
    else if(!found) {
      return res.json({success: false, msg: 'User not found'});
    }
  });
});

function resets(foundData) {
  console.log(foundData.email);
  var mailObj = foundData.email;
  console.log(mailObj);
}
```

In my console I'm getting output as

> finding email undefined
>   undefined

But when I'm trying to display only the `foundData` object I'm getting the output in my console as

```
finding email
[ { _id: 5b3ca69ba87aa42414993682,
    name: 'xxxxx',
    email: 'xxx',
    username: 'xxxxx',
    password: '$2a$10$ZLeRJvizxk62EOS/5mZT6evz7.mFbzf38K6pAzr69O/5I2EZ6WJWO',
    phone: '',
    location: '',
    title: '',
    company: '',
    education: '',
    __v: 0 } ]
```

This is the code for the above output.

```
function resets(foundData) {
  console.log(foundData);
}
```

I want the variable `email` from the `foundData` object. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats because you are trying to access an object property that does not exist.
In the object you log you have an array and inside you have an object. That's because the `MongoDB` find method try to find **every object** matching the conditions and you should use something like `findOne` if you want only one object.

Try this:

```
var mailObj = foundData[0].email;
```